# how to show admob interstitial on app click button setting

Tags: java, android, mobile, admob

strong textAccording to Google's guidelines, it is not recommended to show ads on app load or exit.

How do I show an admob interstitial on app click button setting or play it only once?

> ResultLoadListner,
>               OnItemClickListener, OnTaskCompleted, OnClickListener {

```
    private ListView listView;
    private ListAdapter adapter;
    public static  List<RingtoneDetails> ringtons;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private ImageView stop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Initialise the varialbes
        this.initialiseVariables();

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_home_activity);
        listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.main_grid_view);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        stop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);

        /***/
        /*-----------------admob code------------*/
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(request);
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(getBaseContext());
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(
                R.string.interstitial_id));
        interstitial.loadAd(request);

        // startloading results
        LoadRingtonThread thread = new LoadRingtonThread(HomeActivity.this);
        thread.execute("");

    }

    public void initialiseVariables() {
        ringtons = new ArrayList<RingtoneDetails>();
        adapter = new ListAdapter(HomeActivity.this, ringtons);
    //  SOURCE_URL = this.getResources().getString(R.string.source_url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResultLoad(RingtoneDetails... details) {
        for(RingtoneDetails detail:details){
            ringtons.add(detail);
            this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        RingtonePlayer player=new RingtonePlayer(ringtons.get(position).getRingtoneid(),HomeActivity.this);
        player.startPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case (SettingDialog.CONTACT_CHOOSER_ACTIVITY_CODE):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                try {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    String contactId = contactData.getLastPathSegment();
                    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
                            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, };
                    Cursor localCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            contactData, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
                    localCursor.moveToFirst();


                    String contactID = localCursor.getString(localCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                    String contactDisplayName = localCursor.getString(localCursor
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("display_name"));

                    Uri localUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                            contactID);
                    localCursor.close();
                    ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();

                    localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
                    localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.CUSTOM_RINGTONE,
                            SettingDialog.filePath);
                    getContentResolver().update(localUri, localContentValues,
                            null, null);

                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Ringtone assigned to: " + contactDisplayName,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RingtonePlayer.stopPlaying();
        stop.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stop.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskStart() {
        stop.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You remove this code from `onBackPressed` and add it to your `onClick` handler.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        final Button myButton = ..
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitial.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you
But an error                                                                                                                     @Override
 public void onClick() {
  if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
   interstitial.show();
  }
  super.onClick();

Comment: remove }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
andd add Button error
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gj8vt.png